# how to proportionally resize div with an image inside

Tags: image, html, resize

OK, so I have a full screen background image which uploads via flash

```
flash {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1; }
```

It resizes perfectly, I also have a footer at the bottom as div and 5 images inside it. I aligned all images in one row but as a browser resizes images jump up instead of resizing proportionally. Would appreciate your advice. 
Here is the link to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eglemei/LqBzY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images aren't resizing because you haven't told them to resize.  Proportional resizing isn't default behavior.  Images will only resize themselves in proportion to their containing element if they're giving a `width` or `height` value in percentages.

Once you've specified a percentage `height` or `width`, the images will be scaled according to the closest parent element with an explicitly set `position` attribute (which in your case is 'div#footer'.  If you do set a percentage `width`, then as long as you don't specify a `height` elsewhere, the images will keep their aspect ratio.

Change the CSS for the images to something like this:

```
#sponsors img {
    margin-right: 3%; 
    width:16%;
}
```

You'll also need to remove the `height="100px"` from each `img` tag, otherwise the `img` will use that height.

I've updated your jsFiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/LqBzY/5/